# Calculate time difference between 2 datetime excluding weekend

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to calculate the time difference between two datetime.
Saturday and sunday need to be excluded from the calculation.

For exemple difference between `2023-01-01 10:34:36` and `2023-01-10 15:12:24`

It work well when the start date is a weekday :

```
WITH test AS (
    SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM diff) || ' days '
    || EXTRACT(HOUR FROM diff) || ' hours '
    || EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM diff) || ' minutes '
    || EXTRACT(SECOND FROM diff) || ' seconds ' AS time_diff
FROM (
    SELECT TIMESTAMP '2023-01-10 15:12:24' - TIMESTAMP '2023-01-02 10:34:36' AS diff
) AS diff_query
JOIN (
    SELECT generate_series(
             timestamp '2023-01-02',
             timestamp '2023-01-10',
             interval '3 day'
           ) AS the_day
    ) AS dates
    ON dates.the_day BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2023-01-02 10:34:36' AND TIMESTAMP '2023-01-10 15:12:24'
WHERE EXTRACT('ISODOW' FROM dates.the_day) < 6
)

SELECT * FROM test
```

Output :

```
-----------------------------------------------
| time_diff                                   |
-----------------------------------------------
| 8 days 4 hours 37 minutes 48.000000 seconds |
-----------------------------------------------
```

And if the start day is sunday for exemple, I have two output :

```
WITH test AS (
    SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM diff) || ' days '
    || EXTRACT(HOUR FROM diff) || ' hours '
    || EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM diff) || ' minutes '
    || EXTRACT(SECOND FROM diff) || ' seconds ' AS time_diff
FROM (
    SELECT TIMESTAMP '2023-01-10 15:12:24' - TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 10:34:36' AS diff
) AS diff_query
JOIN (
    SELECT generate_series(
             timestamp '2023-01-01',
             timestamp '2023-01-10',
             interval '3 day'
           ) AS the_day
    ) AS dates
    ON dates.the_day BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 10:34:36' AND TIMESTAMP '2023-01-10 15:12:24'
WHERE EXTRACT('ISODOW' FROM dates.the_day) < 6
)

SELECT * FROM test
```

Output :

```
-----------------------------------------------
| time_diff                                   |
-----------------------------------------------
| 9 days 4 hours 37 minutes 48.000000 seconds |
| 9 days 4 hours 37 minutes 48.000000 seconds |
-----------------------------------------------
```

How to get one row result when the start date is a saturday or sunday ?

Comment: `select distinct ...` ?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.sqlservergeeks.com/find-working-days-between-two-dates-in-sql-server/#:~:text=The%20statement%20DATEDIFF(dd%2C%40,it's%20a%20Saturday%20or%20Sunday.

```
Finding the work days time interval

SELECT
   (DATEDIFF(dd, @fromdate, @todate) + 1)
  -(DATEDIFF(wk, @fromdate, @todate) * 2)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @fromdate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @todate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  As NoOfWeekDays
```